# Sandbox exception "Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible."

Tags: c#, .net, sandbox, appdomain, code-access-security

I am getting the following error when I trying to enable code access security in a sandboxed app domain.

Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'XXX'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

Here is what I have:
 Plugin assembly has a class which implements an interface defined in a sdk assembly. Plugin assembly is not signed. Also, the plugin assembly has [assembly: SecurityTransparent] in AssemblyInfo.cs
 Example:

```
public Class Bar : AbstractBase
{
// This class implements an abstract method defined in the base class

}
```

AbstractBase is defined in the SDK binary and it is signed. Also, when I create a domain in the executing assembly, it is marked as Trusted.

[SecuritySafeCritical]
   public abstract class AbstractBase : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
        {
            public abstract void BaseMethod();

```
[SecurityCritical]
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure)]
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        var lease = (ILease)base.InitializeLifetimeService();
        if (lease != null && lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
        {
            lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        }

        return lease;
    }

    protected void MethodFoo()
    {
    ...
    }

    public virtual Foo FooItIs{get;set;}   // Foo is a class which is a MarshallByRefObject and is implemented in the executing assembly
}
```

Here is what I have tried in AssemblyInfo.cs of SDK binary.

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level2, SkipVerificationInFullTrust = true)]
//[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
```

Finally, there is the executing assembly which creates a domain and applies security restriction. I get the exception when I call CreateInstanceAndUnWrap.

```
private void CreateAppDomain()
    {
        AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
        domainSetup.ApplicationName = "Plugins";
        domainSetup.ApplicationBase = Section.Instance.BaseDirectory;
        domainSetup.ConfigurationFile = domainSetup.ApplicationName + ".config";
        PermissionSet domainPermissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);

        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new IsolatedStorageFilePermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new System.Net.WebPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        domainPermissions.AddPermission(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

        StrongName plugins = typeof(AbstractBase).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
        this.appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainSetup.ApplicationName, null,
            domainSetup, domainPermissions,
            plugins);
    }
```

And here is how I create an instance:

```
action =
                        this.appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
                        Path.Combine(pluginProperties.AssemblyBaseDirectory, pluginProperties.AssemblyName),
                        className) as
                        AbstractBase;
```

I am not sure what it is I am missing or is my architecture wrong in some way for code access security? Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
Here is the stack trace. My UT does the exact same thing described above

at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Infrastructure.MissionControl.Eventing.Agent.Tests.ActionProcessorTests.TestActionExecuted() in ActionProcessorTests.cs: line 196

Comment: `SecurityTransparent` class can not inherit from `SecuritySafeCritical` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is an old post, but I stumbled across it while trying to solve the same problem.  The problem is that you've marked the entire **AbstractBase** class with the `SecuritySafeCritical`, but the **Bar** class, because it is unsigned, must be `SecurityTransparent`.  Deriving a `SecurityTransparent` class from a `SecuritySafeCritical` class is not allowed.

The solution is to remove the `[SecuritySafeCritical]` attribute from the **AbstractBase** class.  Because you've marked the antire assembly as `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers`, the **AbstractBase** class will default to `SecurityTransparent`, and both **AbstractBase** and **Bar** will be Transparent.

Then, when you need access to `SecuritySafeCritical` or `SecurityCritical` functions, you would mark the individual function inside of **AbstractBase** as `SecuritySafeCritical`.  This will allow those methods to access more restricted classes.